Impact of disabling kexec_load_disabled kernel parameter
According to the documenation of the kernel parameters kexec_load_disabled,

This value defaults to 0 (false: kexec_load enabled), but can be set
to 1 (true: kexec_load disabled). Once true, kexec can no longer be
used, and the toggle cannot be set back to false.

What this documentation says is that if this parameter is set to true, i.e. 1, then once the kernel is loaded it cannot be unloaded at runtime and a new kernel loaded in its place. So if kernel 6.10.13 is installed on the machine with the kernel parameter kexec_load_disabled set to 1, will it impact the upgrade of the kernel to ver 6.11.2? Will it prevent it even after a reboot?
Also this parameter if set to true does not prevent entries being manipulated in the boot loader like GRUB. So in GRUB an entry can be made to load some other kernel version. Is my understanding correct?

What the documentation says is that when kexec_load_disabled is enabled (sic),

kexec can no longer be used

That’s all: this only disables kexec, nothing more. kexec is the kernel feature allowing a new kernel to be loaded into memory at runtime, that is to say while the system is running normally, and “booting” it without fully rebooting the system.
So installing a different kernel is still possible, as is rebooting into a new kernel, and modifying the bootloader’s configuration.

Thanks for the answer. The email for your response landed in SPAM folder so did not respond earlier.
